# Как хранить тело html-страницы в базе данных?

Tags: python, sql, selenium

Использую python3+Selenium+MySQL. Стоит задача хранить в базе данных тело веб-страницы (`driver.page_source`)полностью. Какой самый простой и эффективный способ хранения строки такого размера в БД?

Comment: Например, храните в поле типа `CLOB`

Comment: для этого есть специальный тип поля TEXT Types
[почитать можно тут](http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=BLOB) и с [официальной документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

Comment: чем обычный `nvarchar(max)` не угодил?